# geth: view all current contracts on a private testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, contract-debugging, contract-deployment, private-blockchain

How can I query a list of all current contracts with geth?
Is there a way to see the contracts' class names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to run a script in Geth's console, that gets the receipt of each transaction and looks at the `contractAddress` property: [web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt)

Use [web3.eth.getBlock](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetblock) to get the transaction hashes to feed into `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt`.

Contracts' class names are not stored on the blockchain, so they can't be seen.